# Check and compare array with queried post type

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I have a php comparison which is working.

```
if ( $query->get('post_type') == 'motogp-2014')
```

But I need to check multiple post types and I was wondering if there is a short way or keeping this all in one line.

I've tried this...

```
$motogp_seasons = array('motogp-2013','motogp-2014');
if ( $query->get('post_type') == $motogp_seasons )
```

and this...

```
$motogp_seasons = array('motogp-2013','motogp-2014');
if ( in_array( $query->get('post_type'), $motogp_seasons ) )
```

But none seem to work.

Can any help with another php solution please.

Many thanks

Comment: `in_array` should work. I'm not sure what your get function is returning up.

Comment: @Rikesh Oooops, I forgot to make my $motogp_seasons global :-/

Comment: @Joshc you haven't tell us that you are using a function for it

Comment: @RameshGaur I know dude, it was a silly error

Answer (score 1):

Try making your variable global...

```
global $motogp_seasons
```

```
$motogp_seasons = array('motogp-2013','motogp-2014');
function order_events_by_date($query) {
    global $motogp_seasons; 
    if ( in_array( $query->get('post_type'), $motogp_seasons ) ) {
        // Stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: you haven't say in your question that you are using a function for it

Answer (score 0):

you can use `foreach` for traverse your array and then compare it like this

```
$motogp_seasons = array('motogp-2013','motogp-2014');

foreach($motogp_seasons as $motogp_seasons_val)
{ 
 if ($query->get('post_type') == $motogp_seasons_val)
 {
   echo $motogp_seasons_val." is equal <br/>";
 }
 else
 {
   echo $motogp_seasons_val." is not equal <br/>";
 } 
}
```